# A house passed from parents to a child

Tags: word-usage, word-request

As you know, the adjective **hereditary** means:

> (Of characteristics or diseases) passed from the genes of a parent to a child.

- A hereditary disease.

> And also (of titles and positions in society) passed from parent to a child as a right.

But I wonder what adjective you use for passed possessions and belongings **like a house - car. etc.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is similar, but different: *inherited*:

> 2 a : to receive from an ancestor as a right or title descendible by law at the ancestor's death
>   b : to receive as a devise or legacy

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inherited))

> 1 (of money, property, or a title) received as an heir at the death of the previous holder.
>   *‘inherited wealth’*

(source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inherited))

Comment: The question asked for an adjective, so this is quite right. Still, I immediately thought of the noun [heirloom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heirloom).